# How could I compare two files and remove similar rows in them (bash script)

Tags: bash

I have two files of data with similar number of columns. I'd like to save file2 in another file (file3) while I exclude the rows which are existed already in the file1.

```
grep -v -i -f file1 file2> file3
```

But the problem is that the space between columns in the file1 is "\t" while in the other one it is just " ". Therefore this command line doesn't work. 
Any suggestion??

Thanks folks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be nice if you could post some example input as well as expected output. Makes it a lot easier to answer

Answer (score 1):

You can convert tabs to spaces on the fly:

```
grep -vif <(tr '\t' ' ' < file1) file2 > file3
```

This is [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grep -Fxvf file1 file2
```

Switch meanings available from the grep man page.

Answer (score 0):

grep -v -f is problematic because it searches file2 for each line in file1. With large files it will take a very long time. Try this instead:

comm -13 <(cat file1 | tr '\t' ' ' | sort) <(sort file2)