# How could I remove a row which three components of a row in one file is similar to another file?

Tags: bash

I have two files but the format of the data and space character in them are different.
 I want to compare these two files and if the first three columns of each row in file1 are similar to file2, I would like to remove these rows from file2 and save the rest of the file2 in file2.
For example:

```
file1:
4775.00 5215.28 23.9655 7   2.54766 
4568.06 5611.74 22.0619 56  2.36560 

file2:

6944.69 5605.22 22.6416       44 2.31929 0.914626
1619.15 5597.93 23.7979       12 2.38169 0.684619
5986.66 5599.89 23.8822        6 2.99171 0.384949
4568.06 5611.74 22.0619       56 2.36560 0.973764
1365.00 5601.16 23.3325       15 3.78138 0.212834
1787.81 5209.01 23.4643        8 3.34705 0.486087
5287.90 5244.40 21.9990      104 5.28082 0.000269982
4775.00 5215.28 23.9655        7 2.54766 0.467107
9024.54 5235.34 21.0784      120 3.13061 0.0357055
```

Cheers.

Comment: You just posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982186/how-could-i-compare-two-files-and-remove-similar-rows-in-them-bash-script , please update that instead of asking again.

Comment: What does it mean for the columns to be "similar"? Identical? Identical except for whitespace? Values within 0.1% of each other? Values with the same order of magnitude?

Comment: I asked different question although it might look similar in some senses with my other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd forward this when needed. Meanwhile here's a solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

FNR == NR {
    a[$1] = NR
    b[$2] = NR
    c[$3] = NR
    next
}
$1 in a {
    t = a[$1]
    if (b[$2] == t && c[$3] == t) {
        next
    }
}
{
    r[++i] = $0
}
END {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        print r[j] > ARGV[2]
    }
}
```

Warning: It directly modifies the file as required.

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk file1 file2
```

Example result:

```
6944.69 5605.22 22.6416       44 2.31929 0.914626
1619.15 5597.93 23.7979       12 2.38169 0.684619
5986.66 5599.89 23.8822        6 2.99171 0.384949
1365.00 5601.16 23.3325       15 3.78138 0.212834
1787.81 5209.01 23.4643        8 3.34705 0.486087
5287.90 5244.40 21.9990      104 5.28082 0.000269982
9024.54 5235.34 21.0784      120 3.13061 0.0357055
```

If you don't want to have direct modification to the second file, just don't use redirection on the last part:

```
END {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        print r[j]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dalek I hope you could click the check mark on the left as well to accept the answer thanks :)